# padding a input vector, a 4-D matrix, using numpy for a convolutional neural network (CNN)

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, padding

This is the entire code related to my question. You should be able to run this code and see the plots created - by just pasting and running it into your IDE.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.randn(4, 3, 3, 2)
x_pad = np.pad(x, ((0,0), (2, 2), (2, 2), (0,0))\
                   , mode='constant', constant_values = (0,0))
print ("x.shape =\n", x.shape)
print ("x_pad.shape =\n", x_pad.shape)
print ("x[1,1] =\n", x[1,1])
print ("x_pad[1,1] =\n", x_pad[1,1])
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axarr[0].set_title('x')
axarr[0].imshow(x[0,:,:,0])
axarr[1].set_title('x_pad')
axarr[1].imshow(x_pad[0,:,:,0])
```

Specifically, my question is related to these two lines of code:

```
x = np.random.randn(4, 3, 3, 2)
x_pad = np.pad(x, ((0,0), (2, 2), (2, 2), (0,0)), mode='constant', constant_values = (0,0))
```

I want to pad the 2nd and 3rd dimension in `x`. So, I want to pad `x[1]` which has a value of `3` and `x[2]` which also has the value of `3`. Based on the problem that I am solving, `x[0]` and `x[3]`, which contain '4' and '2' respectively, represent something else. `x[0]` represents the number of number of such 3*3 matrices and `x[3]` the channels.

My question is about around how python is representing this information and about how we are interpreting it. Are these the same?

The statement `x = np.random.randn (4, 3, 3, 2)` created a matrix 4 rows by 3 columns and each element in this 4*3 matrix is a 3 row by 2 column matrix. That is how Python is representing the `x_pad`. Is this understanding correct?

If so, then in the `np.pad` statement, we are padding the number of columns in the outer matrix (which is 3 in the 4*3). We are also padding the number of rows, which is 3, in the “3*2” - that is, the number of rows in the inner matrix).

The 3, 3 in (4, 3, 3, 2) was supposed to be part of just one matrix and not the columns of the outer matrix and the rows of the inner matrix? I am having trouble visualizing this? Can someone please clarify. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines:

```
x = np.random.randn(4, 3, 3, 2)
x_pad = np.pad(x, ((0,0), (2, 2), (2, 2), (0,0)), mode='constant', constant_values = (0,0))
```

are equivalent to:

```
x = np.random.randn(4, 3, 3, 2)
x_pad = np.zeros((4, 3+2+2, 3+2+2, 2))
x_pad[:, 2:-2, 2:-2, :] = x
```

You could interpret a 4-D array as being a 2-D array of 2-D arrays if that fits whatever this data represents for you, but numpy internally stores arrays as a 1D array of data; with `x[i,j,k,l]` pointing to `data[l+n3*(k + n2*(j + n1*i))]` where n1, n2, n3 are the lengths of the corresponding axes.

Visualizing 4-D (and higher) arrays is very difficult for humans. You just have to keep track of the indices for the four axes when you deal with such arrays.